Comedy/action movie where a couple move to neighbourhood, are spied on, and people jump from explosion into a pool?
This was definitely released after 2010, but cannot remember a specific year.
Here are some scenes I remember: 

A new couple moves into the neighborhood.
A women from across the street is suspicious, she followed husband or wife at some point.
The couple across the street breaks into and enters the neighbors' house, and got in to some trouble.
A scene from a Chinese restaurant. 
Near the end, everyone jumps into a water pool from a higher building to avoid an explosion of some kind. 

Edit - It's a English movie, a peaceful neighborhood, not in a big city. 
(thanks for the editing suggestions)
This is all I can remember. 

Some more details would be helpful.   Was it a city with lots of buildings?   How old was the couple?   Was it in English?    Do you remember any of the actors?    I don't think you've provided enough detail.    Maybe even, what did you like about the movie?

Do you remember any of the actors/actresses's names?

No not really doesn't remember any from the cast. Couples were like middle aged in the movie, not in a city they live in a quiet and peaceful area. sorry that I cannot provide more, doesn't remember many of the details. it was a good comedy and also with actions.

I also want to remember a actor or actress it will be so easy to remember the movie if  it happens, but Can't remember any of them.

Seems to be Keeping Up wit the Joneses with Zach Galifianakis, Isla Fisher, Jon Hamm and Gal Gadot.
Zach and Isla are the "normal couple".
Jon and Gal the newcomers.
Synopsis on IMDB:

A suburban couple becomes embroiled in an international espionage plot
  when they discover that their seemingly perfect new neighbors are
  government spies.

Synopsis on WikiPedia, but warning it's giving a lot of spoilers.
